# The missing django-allauth tutorial : create a few records in our database

Tags: python, mysql, django, facebook, django-allauth

I am stuck here in [The missing django-allauth tutorial](http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/)

> Now we have to create a few records in our database before django-site
>   and django-allauth will know their heads from a hole in the ground:
>
> > UPDATE django_site SET DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1:8000', name = 'Vort' WHERE
> >     id=1; INSERT INTO socialaccount_socialapp (provider, name, secret,
> >     client_id, `key`) VALUES ("facebook", "Facebook",
> >     "--put-your-own-app-secret-here--", "--put-your-own-app-id-here--",
> >     ''); INSERT INTO socialaccount_socialapp_sites (socialapp_id, site_id)
> >     VALUES (1,1);

How should I update the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to log in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/` and add facebook in social apps.